# Piping STDIO Output To Audio Device In Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio

What I'm looking for is a way to take the stdio output of my short program I wrote and pipe it to an audio device, much in the way that I can with linux. I'm experimenting with short programs that produce audio, and have been piping the putchar output to a file and playing the raw PCM data with Audacity to hear the result. I'd like a program that creates a virtual audio pipeline that I can use the batch "|" pipe operator to move the raw PCM data into the sound card for listening somehow.

Comment: What is the tool you use for that on linux? Maybe that project has Windows binaries..